# Adding Theme and Auto complete option to Tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce-4, codemirror

```
http://www.avoid.org/codemirror-for-tinymce4/ here is the example for tinymce and Codemirror.
```

I want to implement Autocomplete and add theme for codemirror here, it didn't work

```
 tinymce.init({
  selector: '#html',
  plugins: 'codemirror',
  toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | code',
  codemirror: {
    indentOnInit: true, // Whether or not to indent code on init. 
    path: 'CodeMirror', // Path to CodeMirror distribution
    extraKeys: {
       'Ctrl-Space': 'autocomplete' // auto complete didn't working
    },
    config: {
        lineNumbers: true,
        theme: "abcdef", //theme didn't work
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you load the css file for the theme? Also `extraKeys` is a CodeMirror option, so it should probably go under `config`.

Comment: I have added the css theme file (ie abcdef.css) and also tried extraKeys under config, but still not working,